# SQL - Consulta em uma única tabela com valores nulos

Tags: mysql, sql, query

Olá,

Necessito fazer uma consulta filtrada por data. O problema é que as datas não existentes na tabela precisam ser retornadas pela consulta, possuindo todos os outros campos como Nulos.

```
SELECT Data, Servico
FROM controle_equipe
WHERE ((Data >= #4/1/2016#) And (Data <= #5/2/2016#));
```

O grande salto é necessitar retornar todas as datas da do critério de seleção, mesmo não estando contidas na tabela controle_equipe. Já tentei usar IIF, CASE, mas sem sucesso

Comment: Pra trazer os nulos também basta um `WHERE data IS NULL OR ( ... condições ... )` - Quanto as datas, você pode usar `data BETWEEN( data1, data2 )` para fazer as duas comparações de uma vez só. De qualquer forma, data armazenada na ordem da pergunta vai sempre dar problema. No seu formato, `4/2/2006` vai estar dentro do intervalo mostrado.

Answer (score 2):

Veja se assim funciona pra vc:

```
SELECT Data, Servico
FROM controle_equipe
WHERE ((Data >= #4/1/2016#) And (Data <= #5/2/2016#)) OR Data Is Null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Estou acostumado com MS-SQL mas veja se esta sintaxe existe e pode ser aplicada:

```
 SELECT Data, Servico FROM controle_equipe
 WHERE (Data >= '4/1/2016') And (Data <= '5/2/2016'))
 AND IsNull(Data,1) <> 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi você precisa ter uma outra tabela com todas as datas tipo *TCALENDARIO*, aí é só, na cláusula `where`, colocar `controle_equipe.data = TCALENDARIO.data (+)`